# Routing and navigation in Office taskpanes

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, office-app

I have a mean-stack site with `angular-ui-router`, now I want to code an Office add-in with a server and a part of its functionality, and interact with Office.

I have seen `add-in commands`, which permits of going to certain pages from ribbon buttons. But could anyone tell me what should be the best tool to implement navigation (as well as going back & forward) inside the task pane (like `ui-view` and `ui-router` for a web site).

For example, how should we implement the `navbar` and the navigation in the following taskpane?

[image]

Additionally, I have seen some add-ins can launch 2 taskpanes (by 2 ribbon buttons in the same group) at the same time. We can switch between 2 taskpanes, and we can also show them side by side at the same time.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For independent taskpanes, you can specify an unique `TaskpaneId` for each `Action` defined in your manifest. See the [manifest Action documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/action)  for details. *Note that this isn't supported by Outlook.*

The UX you're referencing is using two different types of `control` elements. In this case there are several [Button](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/control#button-control) controls and a [Menu](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/control#menu-dropdown-button-controls) control (the drop-down).

All of the above are defined within your add-in's manifest file. For working examples of add-in commands there is an [Office Add-in Commands Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Sample) available on GitHub. There are several add-in samples included in this repo, each with their own manifest (for example, the [Word manifest](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Word/manifest/CitationSample.xml)).

Answer (score -1):

For routing/navigation it's good to use angular router, so that the application will behave as a single page application.

Regarding navigation through dialogue windows opened by ribbon buttons or interaction among them is not possible till now in my knowledge. Each button should call different modules.